# Random parking problem on a probability distribution

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

[Rényi's Parking Constants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RenyisParkingConstants.html) comes up when one puts down unit length cars on a interval, such that the probability of covering any two interval is the same.

Are there any published results when the distribution is non-uniform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one: Jean-François Marckert, *Parking with density*, Random Structures and Algorithms 18 (4), 364-380 (2001). A preprint version is available on [this page](http://www.labri.fr/perso/marckert/papers.html).